# Postgres group records by consecutive types

Tags: postgresql

I would like to group objects by their consecutive start and end date.

```
+----------+----------------------------+
|  Fruit   | Time                       |
+----------+----------------------------+
| Apple    | 2020-09-08 00:00:00.000000 | 
| Apple    | 2020-09-08 01:00:00.000000 | 
| Orange   | 2020-09-08 02:00:00.000000 | 
| Orange   | 2020-09-08 03:00:00.000000 | 
| Apple    | 2020-09-08 04:00:00.000000 | 
+----------+---------------+------------+
```

The results should look like this:

```
+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|  Fruit   | Start Time                 | End Time                   |
+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Apple    | 2020-09-08 00:00:00.000000 | 2020-09-08 01:00:00.000000 |
| Orange   | 2020-09-08 02:00:00.000000 | 2020-09-08 03:00:00.000000 |
| Apple    | 2020-09-08 04:00:00.000000 | 2020-09-08 04:00:00.000000 |
+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Your demand has an unconsistant meaning, because rows in a table have an arbitrary order, and you supposed falsly that rows are naturally ordered in a table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there would be a window function for this, but I couldn't find which one, so I wrote one myself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function ChangeCnt (
  Cur varchar)
  ReturnS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
As '
  Declare
    x varchar(16);
    y integer;
  Begin
    If (cur <> Current_setting(''custom.pre'')) then
      seLect set_config(''custom.pre'',cur,''F'') Into x;
      y = Current_setting(''custom.cnt'');
      y = y + 1;
      seLect set_config(''custom.cnt'',y::varchar,''F'') Into y;
    End if;
    Return  Current_setting(''custom.cnt'');

  End;
';

CREATE TABLE fruit_data (
  fruitsoort varchar(16),
  changed timeStamp,
  status varchar(255),
  message varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (fruitsoort, changed)
);

INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('appel', '2020-08-25 10:14:00', 'ADDED', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('appel', '2020-08-25 10:15:00', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('peer', '2020-08-25 10:18:00', 'ADDED', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('peer', '2020-08-25 10:17:00', 'IN_PROGRESS', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('peer', '2020-08-25 10:16:00', 'FAILED', 'Remote server responded with code 500'); 
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('peer', '2020-08-25 10:26:10', 'IN_PROGRESS', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('peer', '2020-08-25 10:26:20', 'READY', 'Translated using Google Cloud in 500ms'); 
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('citroen', '2020-08-25 10:21:00', 'ADDED', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('citroen', '2020-08-25 10:22:00', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('citroen', '2020-08-25 10:23:00', 'FAILED', 'Remote server responded with code 403'); 
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('druif', '2020-08-25 10:24:00', 'ADDED', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('banaan', '2020-08-25 10:25:00', 'ADDED', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('banaan', '2020-08-25 10:26:00', 'IN PROGRESS', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('meloen', '2020-08-25 10:27:00', 'ADDED', 'Translating using Google Cloud');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('meloen', '2020-08-25 10:28:00', 'IN PROGRESS', '');
INSERT INTO fruit_data VALUES ('meloen', '2020-08-25 10:29:00', 'READY', '');

Select set_config('custom.pre','',false);
Select set_config('custom.cnt','0',false);

SELECT fruitsoort, changed,
  ChangeCnt(fruitsoort) C
  FROM fruit_data 
  ORDER BY changed , fruitsoort;

Select max(i), min(t), max(t) from (
SELECT fruitsoort I, changed T,
  Changecnt(fruitsoort) C
FROM fruit_data ORDER BY changed , fruitsoort
  ) T group by c order by c;
```

see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/20)

Later I found that writing a function returning a table was a lot simpler as solution, see [db-fiddle 2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/22)

```
create or replace function f_fruit_data ()
  returns table ( 
      f_fruitsoort varchar,
      f_date_start timestamp,
      f_date_end   timestamp
    ) language plpgsql as '
 declare 
    fs_pre varchar(16) = '''';
    ds timestamp;
    de timestamp;
    r record;
 begin
   for r in (select fruitsoort, changed from fruit_data order by changed, fruitsoort)
   loop
     if (r.fruitsoort <> fs_pre) then
       if (fs_pre <> '''') then
         f_fruitsoort = fs_pre;
         f_date_start = ds;
         f_date_end = de;
         return next;
       end if;
       fs_pre = r.fruitsoort;
       ds = r.changed;
     end if;
     de = r.changed;
   end loop;
   if (fs_pre <> '''') then
         f_fruitsoort = fs_pre;
         f_date_start = ds;
         f_date_end = de;
         return next;
   end if;
 end;';

select * from f_fruit_data();
```

Comment: What's wrong with Andriy's answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem, and in this specific case you can solve it using a method that involves two `ROW_NUMBER` calls to identify distinct "islands" of consecutive rows belonging to the same `Fruit`:

```
WITH
  partitioned AS
  (
    SELECT
      Fruit,
      FruitTime,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                   ORDER BY FruitTime ASC) -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY FruitTime ASC) AS IslandID
    FROM
      YourTable
  )
SELECT
  Fruit,
  MIN(FruitTime) AS StartTime,
  MAX(FruitTime) AS EnfTime
FROM
  partitioned
GROUP BY
  Fruit,
  IslandID
ORDER BY
  StartTime ASC
;
```

Demo at dbfiddle.uk: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f7402a206a9f12afec40ce242b2bca92